# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\autors.php on line 8

Tags: mongodb

```
<?php


$connection = new Mongo();

$database = $connection->selectDB('lib');

$collection = $database->selectCollection('autor'); } catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {

    die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());

}

$cursor = $collection->find();

?>
```

help please

Comment: Where's your try block? I can see just a catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {

    $connection = new Mongo();

    $database = $connection->selectDB('lib');

    $collection = $database->selectCollection('autor'); 
} 
catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {

    die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());

}
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch, Try {  help

Answer (score 1):

i see a } before the "catch", but not where you  open the block try.