# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\tagcloud.php on line 155

Tags: mongodb

database;

//define the map function

$map = new MongoCode("function() {"."for (i = 0; i  'sample_articles',

'map' => $map,

'reduce' => $reduce,

'out' => 'tagcount'

);

$db->command($command);

//load all the tags in an array, sorted by frequenct $tags = iterator_to_array($db->selectCollection('tagcount') ->find()->sort(array('value' => -1)));

//custom function for finding the tag with the highest frequency function getBiggestTag($tags)

{

//reset the array to the first element reset($tags);

//get the first key of the associative array $firstKey = key($tags);

//return the value of the first tag document return (int)$tags[$firstKey]['value'];

}

$biggestTag = getBiggestTag($tags);

//compare each tag with the biggest one and assign a weight foreach($tags as &$tag) {

$weight = floor(($tag['value'] / $biggestTag) * 100); switch($weight){

case ($weight = 90):

$tag['class'] = 'class9';

break;



?>

where i'm mistake?

Comment: Why do you think the answer would be fundamentally different to the the answer you accepted on the question you asked a few hours ago? See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059263/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-c-xampp-htdocs-lib-autors-php-on-l

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing quotes for the code in MongoCode, which also seems like you didn't paste the full line as the javascript makes no sense